# Correct Permissions VPS /var/www

Tags: linux, security, debian, permissions

This is a repost of an "off-topic" question on stackoverflow.

My scenario is:

I created a user and added that user to sudoers:

```
visudo
```

```
user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then

```
sudo adduser user www-data
```

and

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www
```

Did a service restart, then tried:

```
scp file user@ip:/var/www
```

Permission denied

The permissions I had applied for folders then files were (not `wp-config.php` or `.htaccess`):

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

I tried:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

I was then able upload files to `/var/www`, but this set permissions to `775`, so I ran:

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Now I can edit files but not write to the folder via  SFTP or SSHFS etc.

My question now is:

How do I write to /var/www without compromising security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sudo` change affects only commands that you run with `sudo` command. Therefore it has no effect in this case.

I would prefer making `user` the owner of all files in `/var/www`. Then, you can `chmod 777` all the directories and `chmod 666` all the files that WP needs write access to. With this, if someone exploits a security issue in WP, he cannot overwrite WP files that easily.

Alternatively you can change the owner to `www-data` for files / directories WP needs write access to. However, this way `user` can not write to those files / directories.

If your server filesystem supports ACLs, you can add an ACL to `/var/www` which gives write permission for some other user than the owner. This can be achieved with `setfacl` command.